# ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout in Redis-6.2.7

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, redis, node-redis

We are using redis version - 6.2.7 in Google Cloud Platform and node-redis package version - 4.6.7 . We are getting the below error in our Node.js 16 server in Google app engine.

```
ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:178:124)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:550:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Code snippet for connecting the redis is below.

```
this.client = redis.createClient({
      socket: { host: redisHost, port: REDISPORT},
    });
    this.client.connect();
    this.client.on("error", (err) => log.error("Error in redis :", err));
```

We also tried configuring `connectTimeout` for 10 seconds in the *createClient* after that we didn't get this error. Should we have to configure the timeout ?
Can we have a proper solution or a work around for this Connection Timeout Error?

Comment: I am not sure what the default timeout is but a common value is 3,000 ms. That is considered a long time in IP terms. There is something wrong with how your networking is configured. Edit your post and add details on the network path from the client to the Redis instance and what how each one is configured. Note: a long connection time will make Redis performance miserable. That means you must find the problem and solve that and not change the timeout to be longer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this piece of code

```js
const client = redis.createClient({ 
    legacyMode: false, 
    socket: {
        connectTimeout: 10000
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a bad recommendation. Increasing the connection timeout is not a good solution or one that will even work. If networking is configured correctly, the connection will happen in milliseconds. Otherwise, it will fail no matter how long the timeout is set to.

Comment: @JohnHanley oh, didn't realize that, I just started using redis, and I thought that's the solution for the connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if this port open for your network:

```
$ telnet <ip_address> <port_number>

$ telnet <domain_name> <port_number>
```